# Forms Authentication with System.DirectoryServices (Active Directory)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ldap, forms-authentication, directoryservices

A VB.NET application that I inherited authenticates users via Forms Authentication and System.DirectoryServices. The app is deployed to IIS 10, Windows 2016 server. After a random number of successful logins, the error message appears for all users trying to login

```
"Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again."
```

When I recycle the app pool, the application begins to work normally again until the next time which may a couple of hours and some times days after.

The web.config is below. Please note, there is no mention of other tags related to the membership provider so nothing to share there.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".CUSTOMNAMEDAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="60" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" />
</authentication>
<authorization><allow users="*" /></authorization>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="40" />
```

I've searched everywhere on the web.

```
 Private Sub LoginUser_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles LoginUser.Authenticate
    Dim path As String = GetLdapPath()
    Dim strDomainandUserName As String = "domain\" & UserId

    ' Authenticate the user against LDAP
    Dim ADEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(path, UserId, LoginUser.Password)
    Dim Searcher As New DirectorySearcher(ADEntry)

    If LoginStatus = "Exist" Then
        Try
             Dim SearchResults As SearchResult = Searcher.FindOne

            If SearchResults Is Nothing Then
                e.Authenticated = False
            Else

                If Session("Authenticated") Is Nothing Then
                    Session("Authenticated") = "Authenticated"
                End If

                If Session("UserIDLogged") Is Nothing Then
                    Session("UserIDLogged") = UserId
                End If

                If Session("UserType") Is Nothing Then
                    Session("UserType") = UserType
                End If

                e.Authenticated = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Logic to clear out UI fields and set e.Authenticated to false
        End Try
    Else
        e.Authenticated = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The application pool for the site is running under a service account that is a member of the IIS_IUSRS group and has Full Control folder permissions to the app's deployment folder in INetPub directory.

Is it possible that App pools's Advanced Settings >> Process Model >> Idle-Timeout set to 20 minutes, the process stops and when someone tries to login, it fails until the process starts up again?

Please advise.

Comment: Update: Changing the app pool config to always be on did not solve the problem.

Comment: Once the error message is hit:
- Procmon confirms that requests to the domain controller no longer go out from the w3wp process
- Wireshark confirms that login requests are received at the network packet level (HTTP) i.e., POST requests (/Account/Login.aspx)
- Wireshark confirms that LDAP traffic no longer is found on the server (LDAP)
- Procmon confirms that there is no network activity by the process (w3wp.exe)
- Wireshark confirms that although there is TCP traffic from my computer to server, there is no TCP/network traffic activity logged in Procmon by w3wp.exe.

Comment: Inside your catch block, are you logging the details of the exception anywhere? That will probably tell you what's wrong.